# Simple Python plugin loader

Tags: python, python-2.x, plugin, dynamic-loading

I have written a simple system to load plugins from files in Python 2.7, and I'd like to see if any of it can be improved upon.

### vedo.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os.path
import inspect

from vedo.event_emitter import EventEmitter
from vedo import VedoPlugin


def _get_module_name(directory, filename):
    return '{0}.{1}'.format(os.path.basename(directory), filename)


def _is_plugin_class(plugin_class):
    return (inspect.isclass(plugin_class) and
            issubclass(plugin_class, VedoPlugin) and
            plugin_class != VedoPlugin)


class Vedo(EventEmitter):
    def __init__(self, plugin_directory):
        self._plugin_directory = plugin_directory
        self._plugins = []

    @property
    def plugin_directory(self):
        return self._plugin_directory

    @property
    def plugins(self):
        return self._plugins

    def load_module(self, module):
        plugin_classes = [c for c in module.__dict__.values() if
                          _is_plugin_class(c)]

        for plugin_class in plugin_classes:
            self.plugins.append(plugin_class(self))

    def load_file(self, name):
        try:
            plugin_module = _get_module_name(self._plugin_directory, name)
            namespace = __import__(plugin_module)
        except ImportError:
            return

        self.load_module(getattr(namespace, name))
```

Each plugin must inherit from `VedoPlugin`, and is loaded by the `Vedo` class.

Here's an example plugin:

### plugins/first.py

```
class MyFirstPlugin(VedoPlugin):
    def __init__(self, vedo):
        super(MyFirstPlugin, self).__init__(vedo)
```

And a quick example of how to use Vedo:

```
vedo = Vedo("./plugins")
vedo.load_file("first")

vedo.plugins[0] # This is an instance of `MyFirstPlugin'
```

Here's some things I'm not too fond of, but I'm not sure what I can do about them:

- Should the private functions in the top of `vedo.py` be moved inside the `Vedo` class?
- Should `load_module` be private? It's only really going to be used when loading files.
- Is there a way to get around the ugliness that is the plugin `__init__` function? Every single plugin will need to have that constructor, which I'm not too happy about.

Comment: What is the purpose of this class, and how do you use it? Optionally, why do you use it?

Comment: The purpose of the class is to load plugins into an array in a (relatively safe) way. I've added an example of how I use it (normally the plugins listen for events on Vedo passed in their constructor) when loading plugins. I use it as it allows other people to develop plugins and drop them into the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your questions:

- No, I think the functions as they are are fine, not everything needs
  to be moved into a class.
- If it's an implementation detail, sure.
- AFAIK no, but if it's otherwise empty the method doesn't have to be
  added.

Also:

- In `load_module` the loop can be more compact by using a combination
  of `list.extend` and `filter`.

  ```python
  def load_module(self, module):
      self.plugins.extend(filter(_is_plugin_class,
                              module.__dict__.values()))
  ```
- The numbered arguments for `str.format` could be left out.

Looks good otherwise.  If you're really concerned with keeping the
internals safe you could also not expose the `plugins` list directly,
but provide a separate accessor instead.

Comment: By "provide a separate accessor", what do you mean? `@property` makes the value itself read-only, however you *could* still modify the array using it's methods. Would it be better to return a copy of the array?

Comment: Depends on whether your users could get hold of the list. In that case maybe have a `get_plugin` method, implement array access on the class, or yes, return a new list copy every time.

Comment: The issue is that I'm not sure if I should "trust" the installed plugins or try to sandbox them as much as possible. I guess there is no proper way to sandbox them, and plugins can only be installed by the user anyway, so hopefully they know what they are doing.